# Compression algorithm that produces url safe data

Tags: algorithm, cookies, character-encoding, compression, urlencode

I'm looking to store cookie data in a compact form.

Is there such a thing as a compression algorithm that produces URL safe output?
Currently my approach is

```
String jsonData = GSON.toJson(data);
byte[] cookieBinaryData = jsonData.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] cookieSnappyData = Snappy.compress(cookieBinaryData);
String cookieBase64Data = new Base64(true).encodeToString(cookieSnappyData);
```

From this `cookieBase64Data` is the one stored inside the cookie.
I would be happy to skip the Base64 hop.

Answer (score 1):

How much are you saving by doing this? Is it worth it?

How about just saving an ID in a cookie and then looking up all the data in a database? Sort of like a long-lived session but you're controlling what data you store so there isn't a huge amount.

Comment: What about website is using a load balancer? Can you keep session data always synced between different boxes?

Comment: When you're using a database you can have two database servers and keep them synced with replication. If you store the info in session objects then you can sync that as well. Each web app container has its own way of configuring clustering. Here is how to configure Tomcat's: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

No. Compression is often a prefix-free code and not a charset. You can use yEnc encoding to safe some bits. Personally I'm not sure why yEnc is doomed. It uses an extended 8 bit ASCII charset and adds a lot less overhead (2%) to the compressed data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YEnc